# MongoDb in Fastcomet shared hosting server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I haven't created an account in [fastcomet](https://www.fastcomet.com/) yet, but I would like to ask the following questions. The site mentions that it supports node.js applications. So that means I can upload an express application right? How about MongoDB and mongoose? I can access MongoDB by typing in the terminal

```
$ mongod --dbpath=data -bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

And the MongoDB URL in my case is

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/ilovearisti
```

How different would it be in fastcommet? I guess I'll have to contact them for the port numbers right?

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 2):

FastComet Team here! Indeed, our hosting plans are fully compatible with Node.js apps and you can have your project hosted on an appropriate package.

If you plan using the MongoDB database type in particular, our experience shows it requires a server solution with more resources and a higher level of private access. This way you would be able to accommodate the operation on an environment suitable for coding with Mongoose on top of the MongoDB driver for Node.js.

As for addressing your URL query, the default IP when starting a ***mongo*** instance is set to 127.0.0.1, so it is configured as *localhost* and port 27017. With this in mind, you only need to make changes on the IP configuration via the ***mongod*** daemon if you are using a remote database setup with a different IP address.

Having said all of the above, we can confirm that if you have created a database called *iloveiristi*, the MongoDB URL will be as follows:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/iloveiristi
```

We hope this information proves useful and we wish you good luck with your project.

Best regards!